# OSX: migrating Postgres db from one Mac to another

Tags: postgresql, macos, backup, database-migration

my Mac unfortunately crashed. I have a Time Machine backup.
Using the Migration Assistant on a new Mac allowed me to get all my documents back, but unfortunately Postgres is not able to start.

So I was trying to manually move my Postgres db from the backup to the freshly installed OSX.

Here are the steps I followed:

- installed a fresh copy of Postgres (v11), downloaded from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
- replaced the /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data folder with the one I dig out from my dead Mac, where I assume my data is stored
- checked/fixed owner of folders (must be 'postgres', I assume)
- started pgAdmin
- entered the PW for postgres user
- clicked on "PostgreSQL 11" server to show databases

This is where I have problems. I am prompted with the same pop-up asking me to enter the password for the user 'postgres'. I type it and I get the following:

[image]

Putting back the original `data` folder allows the server to start properly. So I think there's a problem with my backed-up `data` folder.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How exactly was the backup performed? If it was just a file system backup, it is not surprising that PostgreSQL won't start up. Hire an expert.

Comment: The backup was made with TimeMachine. It was a file system backup. Why is it not surprising? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

A simple file system backup that just copies the files without getting PostgreSQL into backup mode first (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP)) is not a valid backup that you can expect to be able to restore from.

If you get your database to start somehow (e.g, by using [`pg_resetwal`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgresetwal.html), **which will destroy some data**), you will likely have some data corruption. It is probably a good idea to hire a professional who can help you salvage some of your data.